# Width in HTML using px and percent

Tags: html, css

I have two tables that one in the right side's width is fixed and it is `width: 470px`. And another one is the rest of the window width. May problem is that if there is a method that one table width is dynamic and with shrinking the window the width of table in right-hand-side is something like:

```
width:(100% - 470px)
```

it means window width minus the fixed width of the second table is for the first table.

Answer (score 2):

You need `calc`.

```
width: calc(100% - 470px)
```